# Mapping enum types with Hibernate Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, annotations, enums

I have an enum type on my Java model which I'd like to map to a table on the database. I'm working with Hibernate Annotations and I don't know how to do that. Since the answers I search were rather old, I wonder which way is the best?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Do you need something else than the [`@Enumerated`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html) annotation? For example, the following enum:

```
public enum MyEnum { 
    VALUE1, VALUE2; 
}
```

Could be used and annotated like this:

```
private MyEnum myEnum;
@Column(name="myenum") 
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) 
public MyEnum getMyEnum() { 
    return myEnum 
}
```

You can specify how the enum should be persisted in the database with the `EnumType` enum property of the `@Enumerated` annotation. `EnumType.ORDINAL` specifies that the enum will be persisted as an integer value. Here, `myEnum` set to `VALUE1` would be persisted as 0, `VALUE2` as 1, etc.

The alternative is to use `EnumType.STRING` to specify that the enum will be persisted using the name of the enum value that the field is set to. So, applied to the previous example, setting the field `myEnum` to `MyEnum.VALUE1` will persist as `VALUE1`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's exactly what I was looking for. I'm gonna try it out

Comment: What can I type for the @Id field of the enum class?

Comment: @Thiago What? Your enum is typically not an entity, it doesn't have an `@Id` field. Can you update your question to show what you're doing?

Comment: Got it working. I was trying to use enum like an entity AND using its type-safety on Java side,but I understood that Hibernate associates a string to each enum (or integer, depends on EnumType), so that when you ask him to save, he fills with the string on the query automatically. Many thanks!

Comment: could you assign a numerical value to each enum and persist that somehow?

Comment: For those with the same doubt as @Blankman, this is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2751733/3136474).

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum OrderStatus {

    ORDER_CREATED,ORDER_COMPLETED,ORDER_CANCELLED
}

@Entity 
public class PurchaseOrder {
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;
    
}
```

Here `OrderStatus` is a referenced datatype(java object) , now you want to persist this `OrderStatus` in database, but its not possible to directly persist a java object into database
now here `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` comes into picture to convert that `OrderStatus` java object into String so that it can be persisted into DB.