# Map enum in JPA with fixed values?

Tags: java, spring, orm, jpa, enums

I'm looking for the different ways to map an enum using JPA. I especially want to set the integer value of each enum entry and to save only the integer value.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORITY_")
public class Authority implements Serializable {

  public enum Right {
      READ(100), WRITE(200), EDITOR (300);

      private int value;

      Right(int value) { this.value = value; }

      public int getValue() { return value; }
  };

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "AUTHORITY_ID")
  private Long id;

  // the enum to map : 
  private Right right;
}
```

A simple solution is to use the Enumerated annotation with EnumType.ORDINAL:

```
@Column(name = "RIGHT")
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private Right right;
```

But in this case JPA maps the enum index (0,1,2) and not the value I want (100,200,300).

Th two solutions I found do not seem simple...

### First Solution

A solution, [proposed here](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=32048), uses @PrePersist and @PostLoad to convert the enum to an other field and mark the enum field as transient:

```
@Basic
private int intValueForAnEnum;

@PrePersist
void populateDBFields() {
  intValueForAnEnum = right.getValue();
}

@PostLoad
void populateTransientFields() {
  right = Right.valueOf(intValueForAnEnum);
}
```

### Second Solution

The second solution [proposed here](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Java+5+Enums+Persistence+with+Hibernate) proposed a generic conversion object, but still seems heavy and hibernate-oriented (@Type doesn't seem to exist in Java EE):

```
@Type(
    type = "org.appfuse.tutorial.commons.hibernate.GenericEnumUserType",
    parameters = {
            @Parameter(
                name  = "enumClass",                      
                value = "Authority$Right"),
            @Parameter(
                name  = "identifierMethod",
                value = "toInt"),
            @Parameter(
                name  = "valueOfMethod",
                value = "fromInt")
            }
)
```

### Is there any other solutions ?

I've several ideas in mind but I don't know if they exist in JPA:

- use the setter and getter methods of right member of Authority Class when loading and saving the Authority object
- an equivalent idea would be to tell JPA what are the methods of Right enum to convert enum to int and int to enum
- Because I'm using Spring, is there any way to tell JPA to use a specific converter (RightEditor) ?

Comment: It is strange to use ORDINAL somebody sometimes will change places of the items in the enumeration and database will become disaster

Comment: wouldn't the same apply to using Name - somebody may change enum name(s) and they are again out of sync with database...

Comment: I agree with @NatashaKP. Don't use ordinal.
For changing the name, there's no such thing. You are actually deleting the old enum and adding a new one with a new name, so yes, any stored data would be out of sync (semantics, perhaps :P ).

Comment: Yes there are 5 solutions that I know of. See my answer below, where I have a detailed answer.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

For versions earlier than JPA 2.1, JPA provides only two ways to deal with enums,  by their `name` or by their `ordinal`. And the standard JPA doesn't support custom types. So:

- If you want to do custom type conversions, you'll have to use a provider extension (with Hibernate `UserType`, EclipseLink `Converter`, etc). (the second solution). ~or~
- You'll have to use the @PrePersist and @PostLoad trick (the first solution). ~or~
- Annotate getter and setter taking and returning the `int` value ~or~
- Use an integer attribute at the entity level and perform a translation in getters and setters.

I'll illustrate the latest option (this is a basic implementation, tweak it as required):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORITY_")
public class Authority implements Serializable {

    public enum Right {
        READ(100), WRITE(200), EDITOR (300);

        private int value;

        Right(int value) { this.value = value; }    

        public int getValue() { return value; }

        public static Right parse(int id) {
            Right right = null; // Default
            for (Right item : Right.values()) {
                if (item.getValue()==id) {
                    right = item;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return right;
        }

    };

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "AUTHORITY_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "RIGHT_ID")
    private int rightId;

    public Right getRight () {
        return Right.parse(this.rightId);
    }

    public void setRight(Right right) {
        this.rightId = right.getValue();
    }

}
```

Comment: So sad JPA doesn't have native support for this

Comment: @jaime  Agreed!  Is it crazy to think that developers might want to persist an enum as the value of one of its fields/properties instead of its int value or name?  Both of those are extremely "fragile" and refactoring-unfriendly.  And using the name also assumes you are using the same naming convention in both Java and the database.  Take gender for example.  That might be defined as simply 'M' or 'F' in the database but that shouldn't prevent me from using Gender.MALE and Gender.FEMALE in Java, instead of Gender.M or Gender.F.

Comment: I guess a reason could be that the name and ordinal are both guaranteed to be unique, whereas any other values or fields are not. It's true that the order could change (don't use ordinal) and the name could be changed as well (don't change enum names :P), but so could any other value... I'm not sure that I see the great value with adding the ability to store a different value.

Comment: Actually, I do see the value... I would delete that part of my comment above, if I could still edit it :P :D

Comment: JPA2.1 will have the converter support natively. Please see http://somethoughtsonjava.blogspot.fi/2013/10/jpa-21-type-converter-better-way-to.html

Comment: Isn't this approach also fragile? If value changes in code, the code and DB will again be inconsistent. After all, the enum constant  `value` is just a property field that may be changed. It doesn't even have to be unique... I think the DB value of an enum constant should be treated as an "interface" of the enum. It's an interface to the DB, as this enum is intended to be used there. And since the interface-ness is not explicit and may cause mayhem, I think that a designated enum property should be used, named `dbValue`, applying your logic to that `dbValue` rather than some applicative value.

Comment: Wow! My above comment reached exactly the max num of characters allowed!

Comment: There is a better solution below (@Pool) http://stackoverflow.com/a/25246982/6697093

Answer (score 94):

This is now possible with JPA 2.1:

```
@Column(name = "RIGHT")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Right right;
```

Further details:

- https://dzone.com/articles/mapping-enums-done-right
- http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/

Comment: What is now possible? Sure we can use `@Converter`, but `enum` should be handled more elegantly out of the box!

Comment: "Answer" references 2 links that talk of using an `AttributeConverter` BUT quotes some code that does nothing of the sort and doesn't answer the OP.

Comment: @DN1 feel free to improve it

Comment: It's your "answer", so you should "improve it". There already is an answer for `AttributeConverter`

Comment: @DN1I don't use Java or JPA these days, so I'm not in good position of doing so, this is a collaborative website after all. When I was using it, this answer gave me exactly what I needed, not sure what changed since and why AttributeConverter even needed.

Comment: Perfectly working after adding: `@Convert(converter = Converter.class)
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`

Comment: this link is helpful https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa

Answer (score 34):

From JPA 2.1 you can use [AttributeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html).

Create an enumerated class like so:

```
public enum NodeType {

    ROOT("root-node"),
    BRANCH("branch-node"),
    LEAF("leaf-node");

    private final String code;

    private NodeType(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

And create a converter like this:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class NodeTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<NodeType, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(NodeType nodeType) {
        return nodeType.getCode();
    }

    @Override
    public NodeType convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        for (NodeType nodeType : NodeType.values()) {
            if (nodeType.getCode().equals(dbData)) {
                return nodeType;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown database value:" + dbData);
    }
}
```

On the entity you just need:

```
@Column(name = "node_type_code")
```

You luck with `@Converter(autoApply = true)` may vary by container but tested to work on Wildfly 8.1.0. If it doesn't work you can add `@Convert(converter = NodeTypeConverter.class)` on the entity class column.

Comment: "values()" should be "NodeType.values()"

Comment: Can you put `@Converter(autoApply = true)` and `@Convert(converter = NodeTypeConverter.class)` together, or must it need to be either `@Converter` or `@Convert` and both cannot be used together?

Comment: actually seems kind of strange that you can't just do something like `@PersistenceValue("root-node") ROOT,` for each field in the enum, or something like that.

Answer (score 18):

The best approach would be to map a unique ID to each enum type, thus avoiding the pitfalls of ORDINAL and STRING. See this [post](http://blog.chris-ritchie.com/2013/09/mapping-enums-with-fixed-id-in-jpa.html) which outlines 5 ways you can map an enum.

Taken from the link above:

**1&2. Using @Enumerated**

There are currently 2 ways you can map enums within your JPA entities using the @Enumerated annotation. Unfortunately both EnumType.STRING and EnumType.ORDINAL have their limitations.

If you use EnumType.String then renaming one of your enum types will cause your enum value to be out of sync with the values saved in the database. If you use EnumType.ORDINAL then deleting or reordering the types within your enum will cause the values saved in the database to map to the wrong enums types.

Both of these options are fragile. If the enum is modified without performing a database migration, you could jeopodise the integrity of your data.

**3. Lifecycle Callbacks**

A possible solution would to use the JPA lifecycle call back annotations, @PrePersist and @PostLoad. This feels quite ugly as you will now have two variables in your entity. One mapping the value stored in the database, and the other, the actual enum.

**4. Mapping unique ID to each enum type**

The preferred solution is to map your enum to a fixed value, or ID, defined within the enum. Mapping to predefined, fixed value makes your code more robust. Any modification to the order of the enums types, or the refactoring of the names, will not cause any adverse effects.

**5. Using Java EE7 @Convert**

If you are using JPA 2.1 you have the option to use the new @Convert annotation. This requires the creation of a converter class, annotated with @Converter, inside which you would define what values are saved into the database for each enum type. Within your entity you would then annotate your enum with @Convert.

**My preference: (Number 4)**

The reason why I prefer to define my ID's within the enum as oppose to using a converter, is good encapsulation. Only the enum type should know of its ID, and only the entity should know about how it maps the enum to the database.

See the original [post](http://blog.chris-ritchie.com/2013/09/mapping-enums-with-fixed-id-in-jpa.html) for the code example.

Comment: javax.persistence.Converter is simple and with @Converter(autoApply = true) it allows to  keep domain classes free of @Convert annotations

Answer (score 10):

The problem is, I think, that JPA was never incepted with the idea in mind that we could have a complex preexisting Schema already in place.

I think there are two main shortcomings resulting from this, specific to Enum:

1. The limitation of using name() and ordinal(). Why not just mark a getter with @Id, the way we do with @Entity?
2. Enum's have usually representation in the database to allow association with all sorts of metadata, including a proper name, a descriptive name, maybe something with localization etc. We need the easy of use of an Enum combined with the flexibility of an Entity.

Help my cause and vote on [JPA_SPEC-47](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-47)

Would this not be more elegant than using a @Converter to solve the problem?

```
// Note: this code won't work!!
// it is just a sample of how I *would* want it to work!
@Enumerated
public enum Language {
  ENGLISH_US("en-US"),
  ENGLISH_BRITISH("en-BR"),
  FRENCH("fr"),
  FRENCH_CANADIAN("fr-CA");
  @ID
  private String code;
  @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
  private String description;

  Language(String code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public String getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

My own solution to solve this kind of Enum JPA mapping is the following.

**Step 1** - Write the following interface that we will use for all enums that we want to map to a db column:

```java
public interface IDbValue<T extends java.io.Serializable> {

    T getDbVal();

}
```

**Step 2** - Implement a custom generic JPA converter as follows:

```java
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;

public abstract class EnumDbValueConverter<T extends java.io.Serializable, E extends Enum<E> & IDbValue<T>>
        implements AttributeConverter<E, T> {

    private final Class<E> clazz;

    public EnumDbValueConverter(Class<E> clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public T convertToDatabaseColumn(E attribute) {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return attribute.getDbVal();
    }

    @Override
    public E convertToEntityAttribute(T dbData) {
        if (dbData == null) {
            return null;
        }
        for (E e : clazz.getEnumConstants()) {
            if (dbData.equals(e.getDbVal())) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        // handle error as you prefer, for example, using slf4j:
        // log.error("Unable to convert {} to enum {}.", dbData, clazz.getCanonicalName());
        return null;
    }

}
```

This class will convert the enum value `E` to a database field of type `T` (e.g. `String`) by using the `getDbVal()` on enum `E`, and vice versa.

**Step 3** - Let the original enum implement the interface we defined in step 1:

```java
public enum Right implements IDbValue<Integer> {
    READ(100), WRITE(200), EDITOR (300);

    private final Integer dbVal;

    private Right(Integer dbVal) {
        this.dbVal = dbVal;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getDbVal() {
        return dbVal;
    }
}
```

**Step 4** - Extend the converter of step 2 for the `Right` enum of step 3:

```java
public class RightConverter extends EnumDbValueConverter<Integer, Right> {
    public RightConverter() {
        super(Right.class);
    }
}
```

**Step 5** - The final step is to annotate the field in the entity as follows:

```java
@Column(name = "RIGHT")
@Convert(converter = RightConverter.class)
private Right right;
```

### Conclusion

IMHO this is the cleanest and most elegant solution if you have many enums to map and you want to use a particular field of the enum itself as mapping value.

For all others enums in your project that need similar mapping logic, you only have to repeat steps 3 to 5, that is:

- implement the interface `IDbValue` on your enum;
- extend the `EnumDbValueConverter` with only 3 lines of code (you may also do this within your entity to avoid creating a separated class);
- annotate the enum attribute with `@Convert` from `javax.persistence` package.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly close related code of Pascal

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORITY_")
public class Authority implements Serializable {

    public enum Right {
        READ(100), WRITE(200), EDITOR(300);

        private Integer value;

        private Right(Integer value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        // Reverse lookup Right for getting a Key from it's values
        private static final Map<Integer, Right> lookup = new HashMap<Integer, Right>();
        static {
            for (Right item : Right.values())
                lookup.put(item.getValue(), item);
        }

        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public static Right getKey(Integer value) {
            return lookup.get(value);
        }

    };

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "AUTHORITY_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "RIGHT_ID")
    private Integer rightId;

    public Right getRight() {
        return Right.getKey(this.rightId);
    }

    public void setRight(Right right) {
        this.rightId = right.getValue();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do the folowing:

Declare separetly the enum, in it´s own file:

```
public enum RightEnum {
      READ(100), WRITE(200), EDITOR (300);

      private int value;

      private RightEnum (int value) { this.value = value; }


      @Override
      public static Etapa valueOf(Integer value){
           for( RightEnum r : RightEnum .values() ){
              if ( r.getValue().equals(value))
                 return r;
           }
           return null;//or throw exception
     }

      public int getValue() { return value; }


}
```

Declare a new JPA entity named Right

```
@Entity
public class Right{
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    //FIElDS

    // constructor
    public Right(RightEnum rightEnum){
          this.id = rightEnum.getValue();
    }

    public Right getInstance(RightEnum rightEnum){
          return new Right(rightEnum);
    }


}
```

You will also need a converter for receiving this values (JPA 2.1 only and there´s a problem I´ll not discuss here with these enum´s to be directly persisted using the converter, so it will be a one way road only)

```
import mypackage.RightEnum;
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

/**
 * 
 * 
 */
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class RightEnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<RightEnum, Integer>{

    @Override //this method shoudn´t be used, but I implemented anyway, just in case
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(RightEnum attribute) {
        return attribute.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public RightEnum convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        return RightEnum.valueOf(dbData);
    }

}
```

The Authority entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORITY_")
public class Authority implements Serializable {


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "AUTHORITY_ID")
  private Long id;

  // the **Entity** to map : 
  private Right right;

  // the **Enum** to map (not to be persisted or updated) : 
  @Column(name="COLUMN1", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  @Convert(converter = RightEnumConverter.class)
  private RightEnum rightEnum;

}
```

By doing this way, you can´t set directly to the enum field. However, you can set the Right field in Authority using

```
autorithy.setRight( Right.getInstance( RightEnum.READ ) );//for example
```

And if you need to compare, you can use:

```
authority.getRight().equals( RightEnum.READ ); //for example
```

Which is pretty cool, I think. It´s not totally correct, since the converter it´s not intended to be use with enum´s. Actually, the documentation says to never use it for this purpose, you should use the @Enumerated annotation instead. The problem is that there are only two enum types: ORDINAL or STRING, but the ORDINAL is tricky and not safe.

---

However, if it doesn´t satisfy you, you can do something a little more hacky and simpler (or not).

Let´s see.

The RightEnum:

```
public enum RightEnum {
      READ(100), WRITE(200), EDITOR (300);

      private int value;

      private RightEnum (int value) { 
            try {
                  this.value= value;
                  final Field field = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("ordinal");
                  field.setAccessible(true);
                  field.set(this, value);
             } catch (Exception e) {//or use more multicatch if you use JDK 1.7+
                  throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
      }


      @Override
      public static Etapa valueOf(Integer value){
           for( RightEnum r : RightEnum .values() ){
              if ( r.getValue().equals(value))
                 return r;
           }
           return null;//or throw exception
     }

      public int getValue() { return value; }


}
```

and the Authority entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORITY_")
public class Authority implements Serializable {


  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "AUTHORITY_ID")
  private Long id;


  // the **Enum** to map (to be persisted or updated) : 
  @Column(name="COLUMN1")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
  private RightEnum rightEnum;

}
```

In this second idea, its not a perfect situation since we hack the ordinal attribute, but it´s a much smaller coding.

I think that the JPA specification should include the EnumType.ID where the enum value field should be annotated with some kind of @EnumId annotation.