# Persist enum with business value with hibernate annotations

Tags: hibernate, enums, annotations

I have enum ClientType{INTERNAL,ADMIN}, i am able to persist enum with hibernate annotations.
but inserted value is INTERNAL,ADMIN. How can i define my own vlaue. I want table to contain "I" for INTERNAL.
How can i do this hibernate annotations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Map enum in JPA with fixed values ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751733/map-enum-in-jpa-with-fixed-values)

Comment: Thanks for above link. It is very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for this built into Hibernate/JPA that I'm aware of. The best way to do this is to have a `char` property in your entity containing either 'I' or 'A', but to only expose the `ClientType` enum:

```
public enum ClientType() {

    INTERNAL('I'), ADMIN('A');

    private final char dbValue;

    private ClientType(char dbValue) {
        this.dbValue = dbValue;
    }

    public static ClientType findByDbValue(char dbValue) {
        for (ClientType t : ClientType.values()) {
             if (t.dbValue == dbValue) {
                  return t;
             }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Unknown type " + dbValue);
    }

}

@Column
private char clientType;


public ClientType getClientType() {
    return ClientType.findByDbValue(this.clientValue);
}

public void setClientType(ClientType type) {
    this.clientType = type.dbValue;
}
```