# Play! JPA - Get an enum value in a query

Tags: java, jpa, enums, playframework

This is my enum :

```
package enums;

public enum SessionType {
    SESSION_NORMAL(12), SESSION_PERFECT(5), SESSION_SOLO(1);

    private int value;

    private SessionType(int value) {
        this.setValue(value);
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return this.name();
    }

}
```

I've got a models class Session with an attribut type :

```
@Required
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="type")
private SessionType type;
```

And I would like to do a query like that :

```
Session.find("type.value = 1");
```

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the value inside the enum via a SQL query, but you could just use the Ordinal value of the enumeration to store this in the database with the annotation:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
```

That would return 1, 2 or 3 right now, but you can either remap the values (so instead of 1,5,12 you use 1,2,3) or simply add some extra entries to the enumeration until you get the values yo want (if it's so important for the rest of the system that the values are 1,5,12)

Answer (score 1):

By default the enum name is stored in the DB, unless you have some  wrapper or something that saves the actual value.

Therefore you query should be something like the following:

```
Session.find("type='SESSION_SOLO'");
```

Comment: Ok thx, so i can't do numerical condition like :

Session.find("type.value - 5 > 0");

I will create a table with the value of the enum so.

Comment: unfortunately you cannot do that type of query. check this post out they have a solution for what you are after:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751733/map-enum-in-jpa-with-fixed-values

Comment: Pere: Using the ordinal value could cause problems, espcially if someone was to change the order of the enums in the code?
 Similar to the name, if someone changes the name of an enum and the database is no updated there could be serious consequences.