# Implementing enum based dictionary in JPA 2

Tags: java, dictionary, enums, jpa-2.0

Suppose I have a dictionary (i.e. gender: MALE, FEMALE) used in my application.

I'd wish to use this dictionary as a Java `enum`. Moreover, this dictionary values are referenced from a bunch of other tables, so you'd wish to have it a **separate table**.

The Java `enum` cannot be an entity itself. I can use the `enum` attribute (annotated as `@Enumerated`) in my Entity classes but this will save the enumeration (as an Integer, char or String) in **every** table that use this `enum` instead of using a FK to the dictionary table.

**How would you implement such use case?**
- Create a `Dictionary` entity with static method producing `enum` values?
- Modified getter and setter for `Dictionary` which returns an `enum` instead of `Dictionary` instance?
- ...or perhaps you've never needed to persist an `enum` in a separate table?

Answer (score 0):

You can define your dictionary table using integer ID values that match the ordinal numbers of your `enum`.  This is fragile, as many have noted, since you cannot then easily modify your values: JPA relies on the `ordinal()` method when using the [`EnumType.ORDINAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EnumType.html) modifier on your `@Enumerated` annotation.

Marginally better, you can specify `EnumType.STRING`, and define the primary key column of your dictionary table as `VARCHAR`, with values equal to the `enum`'s value names.  This is still fragile, in that you cannot any longer change your `enum` names.

The [answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751733/map-enum-in-jpa-with-fixed-values) shows another option: Sticking with integers in your entity, but translating in your accessors.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with this approach.

**1. Enum where your can store ID**

```
public enum Gender{
 MALE(1L),
 FEMALE(2L);

private final Long id;

Gender(Long id) {
   this.id= id;
}

public Long getId(){
   return id;
}
```

**2. Related to this enum separate Entity**

```
public class RefGenderEntity {
    private Long id;
    private String value;
    ......
}
```

**3. Look at EntityManager#findById**

```
MyObjectThatStoreIdForGender val = ...... ;
RefGenderEntity gender = em.find(RefGenderEntity.class, val.getGenderId());
```

Of course RefGenderEntity table can now be prepopulated with two values, and your will be fine with foreign keys and regular normal working joins.