# Hibernate char column to enum

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, entity, varchar

I have column 'gender' as a VARCHAR(1)/CHAR. 
How to parse values "M"/"F" to java enum with values (MALE, FEMALE) in @Entity class without using

```
@Column(name="gender")
private Character cGender;
```

and converting it manually to enum object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide your own converter:

```
@Convert(converter = GenderConverter.class)
@Column(name="gender")
private Gender gender;
```

Then implement it

```
public class GenderConverter implements AttributeConverter<Gender, Character> {
    @Override
    public Character convertToDatabaseColumn(Gender from) {

        Character value = 'm';

        if (from == Gender.FEMALE) {
            value = 'f';
        }

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Gender convertToEntityAttribute(Character to) {
        Gender g = Gender.MALE;
        if ('f' == to)
            g = Gender.FEMALE;
        }
        return g;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, You're right, the way I propose will only record the enum and not the value.

Comment: Also it's possible to add @Converter(autoApply = true) on coverter class and after that Hibernate will be converting all Gender fields automatically (no need for @Convert(converter = GenderConverter.class)).

Comment: @NikolayYashchenko interesting! I think you should post this as an alternative answer, since I wasn't familiar with that

Comment: See similar problem/solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751733/map-enum-in-jpa-with-fixed-values#25246982

Answer (score 0):

For enum you can use enum type instead to use Character type, eg:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "GENDER")
private Gender gender;
```

Comment: Then i'll get an exception: Unknown name value [M] for enum class [network.models.Gender]. Because column value is not a full name of enum, this is just 1 char M/F.

Comment: yes, you should use as @Alexey Soshin wrote providing your own converter.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @Alexey Soshin:
Also it's possible to add @Converter(autoApply = true) on coverter class and after that Hibernate will be converting all Gender fields automatically (no need for @Convert(converter = GenderConverter.class)).