# Spring JPA is not saving custom values enum type to database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, enums

I have an enum defined as below where the values are supposed to be as -2, -1, 0, 1, 2:

```
public enum Rating {

    EXTREMELY_DISSATISIFIED(-2),
    DISSATISFIED(-1),
    NEUTRAL(0),
    SATISFIED(1),
    EXTREMELY_DISSATIFIED(2);

    private final int rating;

    Rating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return rating;
    }
}
```

In my model, I have an attribute called `rating` as shown below:

```
@Entity
public class Feedback {
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Rating rating;

    public Feedback() {}

    public Rating getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(Rating rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }
}
```

Then, through a RESTful API, I saved rating using the following code:

```
@Service
public class FeedbackService {

    @Autowired
    private FeedbackRepository feedbackRepository;

    public Feedback addFeedback(Feedback feedback) {
        return feedbackRepository.save(feedback);
    }
}
```

So, when I `POST` a request like:

```
{
   "rating": "EXTREMELY_DISSATISFIED"
}
```

I expect to see the value -2 in the POSTgres database. However, I still see 0 as a normal enum would start with 0. How can I adjust this for database to store the values as -2, -1, 0, 1 and 2?

Comment: A JPA provider will not save any custom enum values unless that provider has some special handling for it, and most don't. I know that DataNucleus supports one way, as per http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html#_enums , but depends which provider are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map enum in JPA with fixed values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751733/map-enum-in-jpa-with-fixed-values)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a custom converter with [`@Convert` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html) and 
 [`AttributeConverter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) like this:

```
@Convert(converter = EnumToIntValue.class)
private Rating rating;
```

And write your `EnumToIntValue` converter class, this way:

```
public class EnumToIntValue implements AttributeConverter<Rating, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(final Rating rating) {
        return rating.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Rating convertToEntityAttribute(final int dbData) {
        if (dbData == -2) {
            return Rating.EXTREMELY_DISSATISIFIED;
        } else if (dbData == -1) {
            return Rating.DISSATISFIED;
        } else if (dbData == 0) {
            return Rating.NEUTRAL;
        } else if (dbData == 1) {
            return Rating.SATISFIED;
        }else if(dbData == 2){
            return Rating.EXTREMELY_SATIFIED;
        }else{
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I decided to go with string values instead of int as this does not make a big difference in my case as compared to the complexity to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use an [`AttributeConverter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) which can customize the stored value. [HERE](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/) is a nice tutorial.