# Using Spring JDBC, what is the right way to convert an enum to and from a custom value?

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-jdbc, java-11

I have an enum with custom integer values mapped to each enum because the orders may change often so I can't rely on the ordinal. I see similar questions specific to JPA/Hibernate (this is the exact scenario I have: [Map enum in JPA with fixed values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751733/map-enum-in-jpa-with-fixed-values)), but we are only using JDBC templates in my project so there is no JPA/Hibernate integration.

I can create a `RowMapper` and set the enum manually, but I wanted to avoid doing so because the default behavior for all of the other columns is correct. 
I was able to write the value from the enum by overriding  `setTypeValue` on the enum class, but I'm not sure what the equivalent would be for doing this on read.

Example (from copied question):

```
  public enum Right {
      READ(100), WRITE(200), EDITOR (300);

      private int value;

      Right(int value) { this.value = value; }

      public int getValue() { return value; }
  };
```

I want to be able to use getValue() to set the value in the database and to read it back and map it to the enum (e.g., "200" in the DB needs to map to `Right.WRITE`

Comment: _I have an enum_ - Can you edit the question, to show us your enum, together with some of your data, to help explain _the orders may change often so I can't rely on the ordinal_? Basically, can you show us your code, and how you want to use it? Thank you!

Comment: I can copy/paste the enum in the linked example if that's alright. It's the same thing.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that - thanks for the update, though.

Comment: Even it is not the direct answer of yours, but this fella is the best about all mapping things  https://vladmihalcea.com/

Answer (score 0):

As for now, AFAIK, it is not possible. Also spring [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-persistence.types) on sping-data-jdbc said that enums get mapped on their names. There is an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/issues/1077) btw to implement this kind of feature, but on current spring-data-jdbc version, which is [2.3.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jdbc/2.3.0), I do not know any ways you can do it somehow decoratively (I assume this is what you actually wanted), i.e. annotations.