# Jpa Enum error with Smallint type in postgres

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I want to put enum in my entity. But I have an error with validation which JPA wonts smallint set as enum. How I can solve this issue.

> "Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [status] in table [`order`]; found [int2 (Types#SMALLINT)], but expecting [int4 (Types#INTEGER)]"[enter image description here]
> [image]

[image]

Comment: Did you generate the table using hibernate DDL or SQL query? Your data type for the column is set to `SMALLINT` but here you will `INT`.

Comment: in postgres table column is smallint and I can't change it.

Comment: I want put enum entity but it requires int type

Comment: Is this a requirement to store the enum's ordinal values in a column of type SMALLINT or you don't know how to change the data type for that column?

Comment: I know how to change column to int, but I have no permission to do it.

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't store the ordinal values on DB, as the change in the enum can compromise the data integrity, but you can achieve this using column annotation on the enum field in your entity. like `@Column(columnDefinition = "SMALLINT")
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;`

Comment: I tried that but I have the same error.

Comment: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [status] in table [`order`]; found [int2 (Types#SMALLINT)], but expecting [smallint (Types#INTEGER)]

Comment: see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751733/map-enum-in-jpa-with-fixed-values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add columnDefinition="int2" at OrderStatus in your entity.

```
    @Column(name = "status", columnDefinition = "int2")
    OrderStatus status;
```

Tested on spring boot 2.2.10