# insert List<Enum> into mysql database using java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my Code..

```
List<WeekdayType> weekday = new ArrayList<WeekdayType>();
```

i'm insert the `weekday`  into Database...
Hear `WeekdayType` is Enum

```
public enum WeekdayType {
MONDAY(Calendar.MONDAY), TUESDAY(Calendar.TUESDAY), WEDNESDAY(
        Calendar.WEDNESDAY), THURSDAY(Calendar.THURSDAY), FRIDAY(
        Calendar.FRIDAY), SATURDAY(Calendar.SATURDAY), SUNDAY(
        Calendar.SUNDAY);
private int day;
private WeekdayType(int day) {
    this.day = day;
}
public int getDay() {
    return day;
}}
```

and i'm creating Bean in Hibernate like this..

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="EC_TIMETABLE")
public class TimetableVO
{
-------
-----
@Column(name="REPEAT_DAYS")
    private List<WeekdayType> repeatDays;
//Setter and Getter...
}
```

i'm inserting the values into Database but it giving Error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: EC_TIMETABLE, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(REPEAT_DAYS)]
```

Comment: show your table structure?

Comment: If you want to have a list, you need to have a not 1 to 1 relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to annotate the Enum list with `@Enumerated` annotation.

```
@Column(name="REPEAT_DAYS")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private List<WeekdayType> repeatDays;
```

You can specify how the enum should be persisted in the database with the EnumType enum property of the @Enumerated annotation. EnumType.ORDINAL specifies that the enum will be persisted as an integer value. Here, myEnum set to VALUE1 would be persisted as 0, VALUE2 as 1, etc.

The alternative is to use EnumType.STRING to specify that the enum will be persisted using the name of the enum value that the field is set to. So, applied to the previous example, setting the field myEnum to MyEnum.VALUE1 will persist as VALUE1, etc.

**Update:**
Also you need to specify `columnDefinition` property with all valid values of enum.

```
@Column(name="REPEAT_DAYS", columnDefinition="enum(1,2,3)")
```

Reference: [mapping-enum-types-with-hibernate-annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569053/mapping-enum-types-with-hibernate-annotations)

Comment: Thankyou.. i like your website @Viral Patel

Comment: Is your weekday column in DB is of type NUMBER? If so then you need to use `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)`