# How to map enum(with fields) to entity Column?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, enums

```
public enum TransStatus{
NOT_FOUND(12,"RNF"),
CREATED(43,"created");
private Integer statusCode;
private String statusCodeString;

TransStatus(Integer statusCode,String statusCodeString){
this.statusCode = statusCode;
this.statusCodeString = statusCodeString;
}
public Integer getStatusCode() {
return statusCode;
}
public String getStatusCodeString() {
return statusCodeString;
}
}
```

with Entity class as follows:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="STATUS")
private TransStatus status;
```

is there any way that I can map TransStatus column in my entity to the Integer value of enum that is status code, for example, if I have Enum value as NOT_FOUND TransStatus value in entity should be 12,

edit please notice i have two values of enum status code , status code string , what we want is only status code, we have already tried with "Ordinal" it prints the integer value of the enum not the statusCode in my example

Comment: Use `@Converter` annotation and implement the required converter

Comment: this will work if you put  { "status" : "NOT_FOUND" } however you can convert if you want to use string "created" or "RNF" or also you can create a Sql Enum Type if you are using Postgresql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map enum in JPA with fixed values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751733/map-enum-in-jpa-with-fixed-values)

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can achieve the same by using `@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)`.

See these examples.

[map-enum-in-jpa-with-fixed-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751733/map-enum-in-jpa-with-fixed-values)

[mapping-enum-types-with-hibernate-annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569053/mapping-enum-types-with-hibernate-annotations)